# Postgres SQL Allow COUNT(*) to be zero when filtering by date

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query will get me a COUNT of books within each library. Books are attached to libraries via the shelf table.

The query works fine without the date filtering. It shows me all the counts including library id's with associated counts of zero.

Once I bring in the created_date_time filtering it no longer will include counts of zero.

I want to know counts of books created in the last 30 days GROUPed by Library but also show Library's with 0 counts

```
SELECT l.id as "library_id", COUNT(b.id) AS "book_count"
FROM shelf s 
  LEFT JOIN book b ON s.id = b.shelf_id
  LEFT JOIN library l ON l.id = s.library_id
      WHERE b.created_date_time >= current_date - interval '30' day
AND b.created_date_time < current_date
GROUP BY l.id
```

Comment: Put `AND b.created_date_time < current_date` into the join condition of the left join

Comment: Try left joining in that order: library > shelf > book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group by `library.id`, don't use `LEFT JOIN` on `library`: no good can come out of that.

The easiest way of doing this, is to add your predicate to the  join condition, instead of `WHERE`:

```
SELECT    l.id as "library_id", COUNT(b.id) AS "book_count"
FROM      library l
LEFT JOIN shelf s ON l.id = s.library_id
LEFT JOIN book b ON s.id = b.shelf_id
AND       b.created_date_time >= current_date - interval '30 days'
AND       b.created_date_time <  current_date
GROUP BY  l.id
```

You could also use a conditional aggregate:

```
SELECT    l.id as "library_id",
          COUNT(b.id)
            FILTER (WHERE b.created_date_time >= current_date - interval '30 days'
                    AND   b.created_date_time <  current_date)
            AS "book_count"
FROM      library l
LEFT JOIN shelf s ON l.id = s.library_id
LEFT JOIN book b ON s.id = b.shelf_id
GROUP BY  l.id
```

*Note*: `SUM` returns `NULL` when there are no rows (instead of zero, which is what `COUNT` returns in those situations).

Comment: What do you mean by no good can come of the LEFT JOIN on library?

Comment: @abarax If you `left join` the `library` table too, `library.id` can be `NULL` (depending on your actual data OFC). And (generally speaking) grouping by a null-able column could join multiple groups together (which is usually not intended). But (as you can see) you can avoid this with re-ordering your joins & don't have to over-think about your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

As the Horse mentioned, for a quick fix you could move the date restriction from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT l.id as "library_id", COUNT(b.id) AS "book_count"
FROM shelf s 
LEFT JOIN book b
    ON s.id = b.shelf_id
LEFT JOIN library l
    ON l.id = s.library_id AND
       b.created_date_time >= current_date - interval '30' day AND
       b.created_date_time < current_date
GROUP BY l.id
```

Note that another way of handling this would be to remove the date criteria from the `WHERE` clause and instead use conditional aggregation when tallying the book count:

```
SELECT l.id as "library_id",
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.created_date_time >= current_date - interval '30' day AND
                     b.created_date_time < current_date
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "book_count"
FROM shelf s 
LEFT JOIN book b
    ON s.id = b.shelf_id
LEFT JOIN library l
    ON l.id = s.library_id
GROUP BY l.id
```

Comment: You still have the condition on the outer table in the `WHERE` clause which will remove all rows from `book` that have no match in `shelf`. It should be `LEFT JOIN book b ON s.id = b.shelf_id AND b.created_date_time < current_date`

Comment: This is correct, the WHERE clause seems to be in the wrong place.